# How do I escape a cmd with options and a query?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, curl, escaping

This is how I have it in the script. What's wrong escaping it?

```
"curl --fail $solrIndex/update?commit=true -H \"Content-Type: text/xml\" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'"
```

This is how it executes:

```
curl --fail http://localhost:8080/solr/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">17</int></lst>
</response>
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'text'
```

What works:

```
$ curl --fail http://localhost:8080/solr/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">51</int></lst>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the command in an array instead of a single string

```
cmd=(curl --fail $solrIndex/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>')
```

And execute it with

```
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: I need to pass it as a parameter, echoThenRun "what"?, what = "${cmd[@]}", "cmd[@]", cmd[@], $cmd[@], ${cmd[@]} don't work.

Comment: This should work: `echoThenRun() { local IFS='!'; echo "$*"; "$@"; }; echoThenRun "${cmd[@]}"`

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never quote the whole command; quote the arguments:

```
curl --fail "$solrIndex/update?commit=true" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
```

Comment: I'm passing the cmd as a parameter to a function. ctrl+F curl in http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Whole-Web%20Crawling%20incremental%20script